# C# unable to call protected method from void main

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    abstract class parent
    {
        public abstract void printFirstName();

        protected virtual void printLastName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Watson");
        }

        protected void printMiddlename()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Jane");
        }
    }

    class child: parent
    {
        public override void printFirstName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mary");
        }

        protected override void printLastName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parker");
        }

        public void getMiddleName()
        {
            printMiddlename();
        }
    }


    class Program: child
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            child ch = new child();

            ch.printFirstName();
            ch.getMiddleName();
            //ch.printLastName();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

This code runs properly and prints `Mary Jane`

However, when I uncomment `ch.printLastName();` it showscompile error:

[image]

Why cant my Program Class call protected method of Child Class? especially when The child class has no problem calling the protected method `(printMiddleName)` of Parent class?

Comment: That method is protected, is available only to child from child class. Typo ?

Comment: Can you explain what you _expect_ `protected` to be actually doing for you?  I think you have a misunderstanding of what it does.

Comment: This is basic stuff. Here's the page on [accessibility levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx) which tells you the definition for `protected`.

Comment: All as expected: you can't access **protected** method through the instance ch of  child, only through the instance of Program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are confusing *inheritance* and *access levels*.

Your `Program` class *inherits* the `printFirstName` method from `child`. So *inside* your `Program` class you can access that method:

```
class Program : child
{
    void Method() { this.printFirstName(); }
}
```

From *outside* a class you cannot access `protected` methods. But from *inside* a class you can access the `protected` methods of instance **the same type**:

```
class Program : child
{
    void Method()
    {
        Program p1 = new Program();
        p1.printFirstName(); // this works

        child c1 = new child();
        p1.printFirstName(); // this gives your compiler error
}
```

But you cannot access a `protected` method of an instance of a **different type**, even if it is a type you derived from.

See [C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

**C# specification Section 1.6.2 Accessibility**

> Each member of a class has an associated accessibility, which controls
> the regions of program text that are able to access the member
>
> *public* - Access not limited
>
> *protected* - **Access limited to this class or classes derived from this class**

**Protected** members are accessible only in current class (where it is defined) and classes derived from it.

In another word, you can access it only by `this`.

Answer (score 1):

printLastName is protected. Check the MSDN page about [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> protected
>
> The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.

Answer (score 1):

Protected keyword means that only a type and types that derive from that type can access the member.
so in this scenario you can't accesses Child.printLastName() from program Because it have two levels

Parent.printLastName() -> protected 
Child.printLastName() ->  protected

How inheritance work when you call Child.printLastName() from program  class
it calls Parent.printLastName() -> Child.printLastName() But parent is not accessible that's the region it is showing compilation error.

Solution :-

You can make
**Parent.printLastName() -> Internal access modifier**

**so Parent.printLastName() is accessible in this assembly .**

namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        abstract class parent
        {
            public abstract void printFirstName();

```
        internal virtual void printLastName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Watson");
        }

        public void printMiddlename()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Jane");
        }
    }

   class child : parent
    {
        public override void printFirstName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mary");
        }

        protected override void printLastName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parker");
        }

        public void getMiddleName()
        {
            printMiddlename();
        }
    }


   class Program : child
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            child ch = new child();

            ch.printFirstName();
            ch.getMiddleName();
            ch.printLastName();

            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms the method marked with protected is meaning that the class itself (child) can only access the method or other class inheriting from it.

Program calling the method off 'ch' can not access it, but an instance of Program (as its inheriting child) can call the method.

Comment: That's incorrect - you're describing `private` access modifier, not `protected`

Comment: huh? this is the same explanation, albeit in layman's terms, that people are just quoting from the specification and msdn site...?

Comment: no, your "layman's terms" simplification removes a rather important detail - that a derived class can also access the method with `protected` access modifier. You described `private` access modifier instead. Please fix your answer, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I'll take that feedback, I have edited the answer to include the original questions example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't match your question - you're asking why can't `Program` class call protected method of it's parent (that is, `child` class in your example) - but your code is showing an *instance of `child` class* trying to publicly access a protected method - which fails, as intended.

This would work:

```
printLastName();
```

Or:

```
new Program().printLastName();
```

Comment: Actually if you take the code from the question and replace the ch with this it wont work as its a static method.... not going to down vote as that seems child-ish (lol pun intended ;) )